# husky > pre-commit hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)

Tags: angular, git, pre-commit-hook, husky, git-husky

Suddenly I am getting the "**husky > pre-commit hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)**" error message when I give the `git commit`.

```
(C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe)
> git commit
husky > npm run -s precommit (node v12.18.3)

'pretty-quick' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

husky > pre-commit hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)
```

I tried `git clean` command too. Anyone faced similar issue?

Comment: You can also delete the .git/hook folder and then uninstall and reinstall husky. There are some conflicts with husky generated files and .git/hook/ files. That worked for me

Answer (score 209, accepted):

Husky can prevent you from bad `git commit`, `git push`, and more. If you are getting this error check your ***code syntax***. In case you are getting this error even if your code is valid, please use the below solution.

## #Solution 1:

Delete the `.git/hooks` folder and then do the `npm install` to reinstall husky. There are chances for conflicts with husky-generated files in the `.git/hooks/ files`.

## #Solution 2:

this is a temporary/quick solution.

```
git commit -m "message" --no-verify
```

Comment: It's helped me while no need to check any code syntax and other lints.
Thank you @Sathia

Comment: delete the .git/hook folder in project directory and tried code committing it again and it worked for me like a charm. Thanks !!

Comment: Deleted .git/hooks folder and committed again. This worked for me as well

Comment: It's `hooks` plural. Deleting it worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: delete the .git/hooks worked for me as well!

Comment: why would I want to add --no-verify everytime

Comment: deleting .git/hooks worked for me too!

Comment: You don't even have to reinstall husky. I had to remove .git/hooks and was able to commit

Comment: Because I changed from using npm to yarn, thus has this issue, but fixed with this":  Delete the .git/hook folder and then do the npm install for reinstall husky. There are chances for conflicts with husky-generated files and .git/hook/ files.

Comment: Wonderful solutions, first solutions worked, 2nd not needed to try for me! Thanks

Comment: In case someone stumbles to this place looking for help on php-husky, it was failing for me because `.git` direcotory didn't exist.

Comment: git config --unset core.hooksPath

Comment: how/where to find this folder "git/hook"?

Comment: The first solution didn't work for me. As for the second, is there already some way to not write all the time --no-verify? It works but it stresses me out

Answer (score 10):

I find two temporary solution like that

```
git config --unset core.hooksPath
```

or

```
git commit -m "message" --no-verify
```

Comment: The first command worked for me, but what does it do exactly?

Answer (score 8):

The Comment by @Elio is a much preferred solution, as `--no-verify` is skipping whatever scripts that should run.

I assume here that if the scripts are there it is for a reason...

**Therefore:**

> You can also delete the .git/hook folder and then uninstall and reinstall husky. There are some conflicts with husky generated files and .git/hook/ files. That worked for me

In my case, the uninstall/re-install was not necessary.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I started getting `husky > pre-commit hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)` once some dependencies have been updated. The problem was solved by changing Husky's pre-commit linting command to `npm run lint` (usually this one works fine in most cases) in the Husky file:

```json
// .huskyrc.json
{
  "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm run lint"
  }
}
```

Note: the solution works if the `lint` script is declared in your `package.json`; in my case I have:

```json
// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tsc && eslint \"src/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}\" --quiet --fix"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For me I had to add

```
"lint-staged": {
  "**/*": "prettier --write --ignore-unknown"
},
```

to my `package.json`

Comment: You forgot to add that lint-staged is a separate npm package

Answer (score 1):

I came with the same annoying error message when commit to a electron.js project. Adding `--no-verify` option works, but it's also a bit annoying that I have to do it everytime when commit.

Then I found the something related to precommit in `package.json` file:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "precommit": "lint-staged",
    ...
  }
}
```

Just **remove** the above line solved my problem.

Comment: i suppose it switch off husky hook, similar to remove hooks from .git folder. this way just  bypass the problem but not solving it

Comment: @ArtemVertiy Husky no longer supports precommit hooks in package.json, hooks are defined in .husky folder

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me on [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/) application.
Use prettier **version 2** instead of **version 3**.

**My solution:**

```
npm i -D  prettier@2.8.8
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons why it happens is because your **pre-commit file** contains `npm test` and if you don't have any tests then you will get this error. The way to fix it is either to add tests or remove `npm test` from **pre-commit file** or add some another your script like `npm run lint`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was also seeing:

```
sh: eslint: command not found
```

which I fixed with:

```
npm install -g eslint
```

Then the error with husky disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted .git/hooks and that helps me. install/uninstall nothing.

```
rm -rf .git/hooks
```