# husky pre-commit hook commits all CRLF end of line changes

Tags: node.js, git, visual-studio-code, newline, husky

On Windows 10, IDE is Visual Studio Code

I am working with a Ts.Ed node environment for work. We have a repository that is originally written with LF line breaks. As a Windows user, my IDE converts all of my files to CRLF. I have to manually convert all files to LF if I want to keep consistent.

One of our repositories with the above setting is not allowing me to commit because of [this Husky error (as displayed here in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63943401/husky-pre-commit-hook-failed-add-no-verify-to-bypass). After following the instructions in the Stack Overflow link to fix it, it finally lets me commit my work, however it commits almost every other file in the system that I haven't touched but have decided to commit itself in git because of the LF-> CRLF change.

Is there a way I can prevent this from happening without having to manually convert all files to LF?

Comment: Consider adding `* text eol=crlf` to your `.git/info/attributes`. Note that this is a Really Big Hammer and you might want to trim it down to, say, `*.cc` and `*.hpp` or some such, or add exceptions like `*.jpg binary`. The `eol=crlf` tells Git that *Git* should change LF-only to CRLF "on the way out" of Git, and CRLF to LF-only "on the way in".

Comment: The problem here is that this damages binary files, but if there are no binary files in the repository, there's nothing to damage. Putting this in your `.git/info/attributes` means it's a private setting just for you, rather than a setting that applies to everyone.