# Getting ERR! Missing script: "test", when running git commit -m "commit message". I am implementing husky. npx husky add .husky/pre-commit "npm test"

Tags: git, kotlin, npm

```
> git commit -m "commit message"
npm ERR! Missing script: "test"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2022-01-25T15_32_42_915Z-debug-0.log
husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 1 (error)
```

The **.husky/pre-commit** script includes an **npm test** which looks for that script inside **package.json**. The **test** script doesn't exist and I can only commit with the **--no-verify** flag to skip, which consequently skips the **npx lint-staged** step.

Comment: Can you... create the missing script?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63943401/husky-pre-commit-hook-failed-add-no-verify-to-bypass) solve your issue?

Comment: You have installed a pre-commit hook. Your pre-commit hook has a bug in it. That's all we can tell you here, because you have not told us where you got your pre-commit hook or what you'd like it to test. See also [ask].